# Laravel: Using Append Field in Where Condition

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm new using Laravel.
I have a model Member with 'dateOfBirth' field and an append field called 'category' (it has information with sports category depending from age like (Under 10, Under 15, Junior, Senior, Veteran...) so it cannot be in DB because it change every sport season.

But I need filtering members having a condition depending on age (cagegory).
The filter let the user filter for **MORE THAN ONE CATEGORY**. Is my main problem.

```
    $all = Member::where('status', '<>', 'pending');
    if ($category != null) {
        $all = $all->whereIn('category', $category);
    }
```

This is not working because I have an error telling that column doesn't exist:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category' in 'where clause'
```

Is there a way that I can solve it?

Comment: Eloquent, as you can see can't search table by custom appended field. Instead, you will need to implement something like `$all->where(['dateOfBirth', '<=', 10])` or what is suitable for your case. Meaning, you need to convert that senior/junior/under15 tag (category) to the value suitable for searching in actual table's field.

Comment: Show us the logic behind the `category` calculation. In this way, you could never achieve this result as the `category` field is being appended to the model after it's been hydrated from a database fetch.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy the problem (maybe I didn't explain myself) is that I want to let the user filter for more than one category.... Is the reason I use a 'whereIn' clause in the example. I'm gonna edit to make it clearly

Comment: The appended properties are appended after the database fetch has been completed. Easiest solution is to simply filter the collection after the fact. `Member::where('status', '<>', 'pending')->get()->whereIn('category', $category)`. This should be reasonably performant as long as you aren't dealing with 10s of thousands of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **switch case**, which allows you to customize SQL queries based on different conditions for each category.

```php
$members = Member::where('status', '<>', 'pending');

if ($category !== null) {
    switch ($category) {
        case 'Under 10':
            $members = $members->where('dateOfBirth', '>=', now()->subYears(10));
            break;
        case 'Under 15':
            $members = $members->where('dateOfBirth', '>=', now()->subYears(15));
            break;
        case 'Junior':
            // Conditions for Junior category
            break;
        case 'Senior':
            // Conditions for Senior category
            break;
        case 'Veteran':
            // Conditions for Veteran category
            break;
    }
}

$members = $members->get();
```

---

**Modify: Can filter multiple categories**

If you need to filter multiple categories, you can change $category to an array and iterate over the array to apply different conditions. This way the conditions of each category can be applied to the query.

This is the modified code:

```php
$members = Member::where('status', '<>', 'pending');

if (!empty($categories)) {
    $members = $members->where(function ($query) use ($categories) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            switch ($category) {
                case 'Under 10':
                    $query->orWhere('dateOfBirth', '>=', now()->subYears(10));
                    break;
                case 'Under 15':
                    $query->orWhere('dateOfBirth', '>=', now()->subYears(15));
                    break;
                case 'Junior':
                    // Add conditions for the Junior category here
                    break;
                case 'Senior':
                    // Add conditions for the Senior category here
                    break;
                case 'Veteran':
                    // Add conditions for the Veteran category here
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

$members = $members->get();
```

The `orWhere()` used here ensures that if any of the categories match, that member will be included in the results.

If you want all selected category conditions to be met (that is, AND logic), you should adjust it to `where()`.

Comment: And What happen if I want to select more than one category? in fact... this is my problem... This is why my main question use "whereIn" clause

Comment: Thanks @yasiao your answer was very usefull. Finally I use `orWhereBetween` but the sintaxis helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with append column conditioning in laravel.
You can use whereRaw clause with mysql raw sql query.